# Search JSON between two dates

Tags: javascript, json, angular, datetime

I have a JSON object which needs to be searched if I input a angular form with two dates

I tried searching using a single date angular form control.

**template code:**

```
<div>
   <div class="card w-75">
      <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Invoice summary</h5>
          <hr>
          <p class="card-text">Total revenue made by this venue: <strong> 
   {{totalRevenue}}</strong></p>
          <p *ngIf="invoicesFiltered === true" class="card-text">Revenue 
made on <strong>{{inputInvoiceDate}}</strong> is <strong> 
{{filteredTotalRevenue}}</strong></p>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div>
      <div style="float:left;">
          <label for="queryInvoiceDate">Start Date:</label>
          <input
            #queryInvoiceDate
            (change)="filterInvoice(queryInvoiceDate.valueAsDate)"
            type="date"
            class="form-control"
            style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="filteredInvoices" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="10">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Advertiser Acct Balance</th>
              <th>Service Fee Amt</th>
              <th>Target Amt for Venue</th>
              <th>Venue Acct Balance</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let invoice of mf.data">
              <td>{{invoice.acntbalances}}</td>
              <td>{{invoice.servicefeeamount}}</td>
              <td>{{invoice.targetamount}}</td>
              <td>{{invoice.targetbalance}}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">
                    <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[10,15,20]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
      </table>
  </div>
```

**component code:**

```
filterInvoice(queryInvoiceDate: any) {
    this.inputInvoiceDate = queryInvoiceDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    this.filteredInvoices = (queryInvoiceDate) ?
    this.invoices.filter(i => 
       i.timestamp.includes(queryInvoiceDate.toISOString().split('T')[0])) : this.invoices;
    console.log(queryInvoiceDate.toISOString());
    this.filteredTotalRevenue = this.filteredInvoices.reduce((sum, invoice) => {
  return sum + invoice.targetamount; }, 0);
}
```

What would i need to do if I want to pass two dates and search for all JSON values falling between the passed dates and specific timestamps?

Comment: What did you try? Please review Help pages for guidelines on how to post, and what kinds of questions this site is designed to handle. Adding an MVE of what you tried is helpful, and required. Also, please check spelling/typos/capitalization. Thanks. Welcome to SO. I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) if you need to do anything with dates in javascript that isn't trivial. That is likely to be the case if you are writing a real-world application as opposed to a theoretical exercise. Javascript dates are messy and nasty, and you can see that you are already doing ugly things like `.toISOString().split('T')[0]` in order to extract the date. In momentjs, you can do something like `moment(queryInvoiceDate1).isBefore(moment(i.timestamp)) && moment(queryInvoiceDate2).isAfter(moment(i.timestamp))` to filter the invoices by the date range. This will let you write much more readable and maintainable code.

On the other hand, the nice thing about ISO strings is that they can be compared vie lexicographical (alphabetical) sort, so '2018-09-01' is > '2018-08-01' and < '2018-09-03' for instance. So you could use your current method of extracting the date from the ISO string and simply use >= and <= operators in the filter.

Comment: thank you very much. That was really helpful. Appreciate it.